# How to call a constexpr function which returns void by a constexpr expression?

Tags: c++, constexpr

The call to `test` failed to compile but `test1` succeeded

```
constexpr void test(int n)
{
    return;
}

constexpr int test1(int n)
{
    return n;
}


int main()
{
    constexpr test(5); // Failed
    constexpr (test)(5); // Also failed
    constexpr auto n = test1(5);  // OK
    return 0;
}
```

I could misuse something or it is not a real case. Please help to explain. I cannot not find the same question on SO

**Output**:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:14:15: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'test' with no type [-fpermissive]
   14 |     constexpr test(5); // Failed
      |               ^~~~
<source>:15:16: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'test' with no type [-fpermissive]
   15 |     constexpr (test)(5); // Also failed
      |                ^~~~
```

Comment: it fails because `constexpr test(5);`  is not the right syntax to call a function. You should include the compiler error in the question, it is actually rather clear on wahts wrong. If you dont understand the error message, no problem, others can explain.

Comment: fwiw, `const test(5);` would be wrong for the same reason, the `constexpr` is not that relevant

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I updated the error output. How about the second one ?? It also fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are using the wrong syntax. The compiler gets confused because it expects that you want to declare a variable called `test` and complains that you cannot do that without declaring its type. This is what the compiler expects:

```
constexpr int test(5);     // OK
constexpr int (test_x)(5); // also OK
```

And this is what you you actually want:

```
test(5);
(test)(5);  // ok, but unusual to put the () here
```

You do not need to explicitly state that you are calling a `constexpr` method. `constexpr` is part of the declaration, not of the function call.